# Using Function and Multiple conditions

Tags: r

Question is to Create a function ans(a, b, x, y), which returns the value x, if a=1 and b=1, 
the value y, if a=1 and b=0, and the value 0 otherwise. 
I have tried this code:

```
ans <- function(a,b,x,y) if(a<-1&b<-1){return(x)} & if(a<-1&b<-0) 
{return(y)} else{return(0)}
```

but that code is not working. Kindly help me finding typo in it.

Comment: To compare values you need to use `==` and not `<-`

Answer (score 1):

You need to work like this:

```
ans <- function(a,b,x,y) {

  if( a == 1 & b == 1) {

    return(x)

  } else if (a == 1 & b == 0) {

    return(y)

  } else {

    0

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that AlexB is maintaining the syntax of the OP.  But as an FYI for the OP, it's a good practice to assign the return value to a variable and return the variable only once at the end of the function. So something like:

```
ans <- function(a,b,x,y) {

      retVal <- 0

      if( a == 1 & b == 1) {

            retVal <- x

      } else if (a == 1 & b == 0) {

            retVal <- y

      }

      return(retVal)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

```
ans <- function(a, b, x, y){
  if(a == 1 & b %in% 0:1){
    if(b == 1) x else  y
  } else 0
}
```

Test cases:

```
x <- pi
y <- sqrt(2)

ans(1, 1, x, y)
#[1] 3.141593
ans(1, 0, x, y)
#[1] 1.414214
ans(1, -1, x, y)
#[1] 0
ans(0, 1, x, y)
#[1] 0
```